# How to calculate -1.10 + 0.0110 in binary?

Tags: floating-point, binary, subtraction

I need help with the binary subtraction of the floating point numbers. I have to do -1.10 + 0.0110.

a) I do not understand how to understand -1.10. If something is signed, the most upper bit has to bit "1". Here I do not know the amount of bits, hence I have no idea, if -1.10 contains zeros or ones to the left. What does it mean, to use "-" before the binary?

b) The 1) in picture shows my subtraction and check. Obviously, I do something wrong. If I borrow from the left, should I have "1"-s at all bit positions to the left in the minuend, or should I take only as much ones, as necessary for the subtrahend? What I am doing wrong here?

c) In 2) I try to use the two's complement. Should I complement both numbers, or only the subtrahend? Should I complement it back after the subtraction? Should I align to the decimal point? What I am doing wrong here?

The result has to be 1.00, if rounded after the machine addition to 2 digits. But I do not get 1.00 anyway.

Could you show me how to calculate this particular example and answer the questions from a),b),c)? I came to a standstill in my numerical lecture because of my binary sins.

[image: Example]

Comment: Since you are given numbers in sign and magnitude form, I would forget about 2's complement unless you have been told to use it. Could you calculate -(1.10 - 0.0110)?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes in this way. I was struggling to subtract a bigger number from a smaller one. Does one allowed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base 2 math:

`-1.10 + 0.0110` is like `-(1.10 - 0.0110)`

`1.10 - 0.0110` is

```
   1.10
 - 0.0110
 --------
   1.0010
```

Round to 2 places after the `.` , the 1.0010 goes to 1.00 or 1.01.  Being half-way, the typical rounding is to the *even* value.

```
   1.00
```

Applying the `-` from the beginning, final answer:

```
  -1.00
```

---

Floating point encoding overwhelmingly does not use 2's complement, but sign-magnitude with an biased exponent. [@Patricia Shanahan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657969/how-to-calculate-1-10-0-0110-in-binary/61666365#comment109068061_61657969)

Comment: I was told that "-" is represented by the upper bit set to "1". Seeing "-1100" one can say either 1) 1100 is 12, so the number is -12, oder 2) 1100 is negative, so it is -4. How to read minus correctly and why they put the minus with a binary number?

Comment: Kirill Comment mixes a number of issues. First, with "and why they put the minus with a binary number?" --> For the same reason as decimal numbers : to indicate a negative value.  -12(base 10) is as -1100(base 2).  With "1100 is negative, so it is -4.", it appears you are think of a 4-bit 2's complement integer encoding.  With floating point, set aside 2's complement - not applicable here.